# Simple Segmentation Fault Proglem

Tags: c++, fault

```
    PNG * original;
    original->readFromFile("in.png");
    int width  = original->width(); 
    int height = original->height();
```

I'm getting a segmentation fault in this bit of code. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you ever initialize `PNG* original`? Otherwise, dereferencing it will be undefined.

Comment: -1 'cause you really could have tryied a bit harder on that one. At least try to solve your problems before you ask for help.

Answer (score 2):

You must allocate memory, because `original` it's just a pointer.

Like this:

```
PNG *original = new PNG();
```

Answer (score 1):

You are dereferencing `original` without first having assigned anything to it.

You declared it as a `PNG *` but did not assign an object instance to that pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you don't need to use a pointer

```
PNG original;
original.readFromFile("in.png");
int width  = original.width(); 
int height = original.height();
```

Despite what some newbies seem to think pointers are not obligatory.